# Synchronous fetching data NSOperationQueue or NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue, nsurlsessiondatatask

In my app , we have to make 3 server calls when we click on the login button.

```
1) will make a server call to get an OAuth token for user credentials
2) with the token from (1) we will get user privileges
3) with the token from (1) and with the valid privilege from (2) we will get the data to be displayed on the page after login in a tableview.
```

I'm confused with the approach to take for this. Would it be a good approach to use operationqueue adding dependencies or to use NSURLSession tasks ?

According to one of the stack overflow solutions for this - [Best practices for making a queue of NSURLSessionTasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618681/best-practices-for-making-a-queue-of-nsurlsessiontasks) , 
NSURLSession does not have any logic about ordering requests it will just call the completionBlock of whatever finishes first even when setting the maximum number of connections per host to 1

If there is any other better approach let me know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `NSURLSession` tasks. first call first api method and you will get response in completion handler(block). now store it in any public property (as you want to use it again) within completion handler. From that completion handler call second api method and from the completion handler of that second method, call third api method by passing response and using public property which have first api method's object stored.

Completion handler or blocks getting called only when response is arrived so by this way you can manage your api calls.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Is this method tried or guessed ? because , adding a datatask inside a datatask is giving me an error

Comment: No i had used this in past. i had pass data to api which come from other api from completion handler.

Comment: Make three different methods to perform this three operation. from method one's completion handler call method 2 with passing required data and from method 2's completion handler call method 3 by passing required data.

Comment: This method would work perfectly, I have done it in past too.

Comment: Thank you guys :-)

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, a *simplified* version of your code utilising the traditional approach of "completion handlers" may look as follows:

```
fetchOAuthToken() { (token, error) in
    if let token = token {
        fetchPrivileges(token: token) { (privileges, error) in
            if let privileges = privileges {
               fetchData(token: token, privileges: privileges) { (data, error) in 
                   if let data = data {
                       // ... 
                   }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that for brevity only, the code does not contain error handling and no means for cancellation.

The dependencies are established through the *continuations* - that is, the completion handlers.

Another approach utilising "Scala-like" futures will look as below (using *Promises* is quite similar approach):

```
fetchOAuthToken().flatMap { token in
    fetchPrivileges(token: token).flatMap { privileges in
        fetchData(token: token, privileges).map { data in
            // ...
        }
    }
}.onFailure { error in
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

The statement above creates one task which is composed out of three.

This approach contains full fledged error handling, even though it might not be obvious. The production version won't differ much than this snippet above - it may only add a means for cancellation.

There are a few third party libraries implementing Scala-like futures or Promises.

One approach adding cancellation, may look as follows:

```
let cr = CancellationRequest()
fetchOAuthToken(ct: cr.token).flatMap { token in
    fetchPrivileges(token: token, ct: cr.token).flatMap { privileges in
        fetchData(token: token, privileges, ct: cr.token).map { data in
            // ...
        }
    }
}.onFailure { error in
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Later, you can cancel the composed task (what ever it is currently executing):

```
cr.cancel()
```

**Note:**

This problem *can* be solved with `NSOperations`, too. However, it would require three subclasses of `NSOperation`, and one or two thread-safe helper classes which will be used to "transfer" the result of Op1 to input of Op2, and the result of Op2 to the input of Op3. I would estimate that this will take about 500 lines of code -- too much for an answer on SO ;)

The "Scala-like" futures approach requires a third party library. The cancellation requires another - or your own implementation (which is not that difficult), or one library that provide all in one.

Answer (score -2):

```
// Importing the UIKit framework for iOS app development
import UIKit

// ViewController class conforming to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // Private instance of NewViewModel
    private var newviewmodel: NewViewModel?

    // IBOutlet for the UITableView in the storyboard
    @IBOutlet weak var mTableview: UITableView!

    // Override function called when the view loads
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set up the table view and initialize the view model
        SetUpTableview()
        newviewmodel = NewViewModel()

        // Fetch todos using the view model and reload the table view on completion
        newviewmodel?.fetchTodos { [weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.mTableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to set up the table view
    func SetUpTableview() {
        mTableview.delegate = self
        mTableview.dataSource = self
        mTableview.register(UINib(nibName: "NewTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "NewTableViewCell")
    }

    // Number of sections in the table view
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Number of rows in the table view, using the count from the view model
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newviewmodel?.numberOfTodos ?? 0
    }

    // Configure and return a cell for the table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewTableViewCell", for: indexPath)  as! NewTableViewCell
        cell.Title.text = newviewmodel?.getTodoAtIndex(indexPath.row).title
        cell.CompleteLbl.text = "\(String(describing: newviewmodel?.getTodoAtIndex(indexPath.row).completed))"
        cell.Id.text = "\(newviewmodel?.getTodoAtIndex(indexPath.row).id ?? 0)"
        cell.UserName.text = "\(newviewmodel?.getTodoAtIndex(indexPath.row).userId ?? 0)"
        return cell
    }

    // Set the height for each row in the table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and explain how your code is answer to the original question.